# Automatically refresh image dahboard node-red

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, node-red

my flow is a timestamp that is injected every minute into the node that takes the photo via raspberry and creates a file called pictures.JPEG then later through a template node I visualize the image, however to view the new image it is necessary to reload the page, how can I make sure that only the image is reloaded automatically when a new photo is taken?
I have to use the same photo name becaue I don't care save the image

This is my simple template node:

`<div>
 <img src="/photo1.JPEG" id="photo" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query parameter for the current time. Everytime the page is refreshed the browser will reload the image, but the back-end server shouldn't care about the query parameter.

```js
<img src="/photo1.JPEG?{{timestamp}}" id="photo" width="100%" height="100%">

@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
    public timestamp = new Date().getTime();
}
```

Comment: if i copy this code in template node of ui interface, the image is not visualized.  @Component({})
export class MyComponent {
    public timestamp = new Date().getTime();
}  this code is not processed by the template node